# HERE-sdk.aar not found

Tags: android, here-api

HERE-sdk.aar not found.
I want to use below tutorial:
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-guidance.html
But the NavigationManager class is not working.
Please help.

Comment: "HERE-sdk.aar not found" : are you using starter sdk or premium sdk?

Answer (score 1):

1) Check that you actually put `HERE-sdk.aar` file into `libs` folder of your project
2) Check that your `build.gradle` file contains this part:

```
repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs' 
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'HERE-sdk', ext:'aar') 
}
```

You can always look on a basic example setup https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/BasicMapSolutionGradle.zip

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am now not using that SDK as this has issues with android version.